# Media query for the Blackberry 9900 bold?

Tags: css, blackberry, responsive-design, media-queries

I need media query which will only be applied on Blackberry 9900 bold.

I have tried with `@media only screen and (max-height: 480px) and (max-width: 640px)` but it wasn't successful.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you post a URL we can look at or some HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that helped fix the problem is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0" />
```

Comment: I have media query for all smartphones. but I have a problem because Blackberry 9900 bold not detect site as a mobile. It detect site as a desktop.

Comment: The problem is solved with this code:

<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0" />


Thanks for help!

Comment: @SrdjanDejanovic You should put an answer with that and accept it for future viewers, or I could do it if you want

Comment: I have same issue, when I put the meta tag, it is fine work for BB-9900, but it is disturbed other device as well.